# How to go about implementing a custom TextView in GTK3?

Tags: gtk3

I would like to write a very simple text editor with a custom widget for drawing the text. I use GTK3. So far, I've come up with something like this:

`Window -> Vertical Box -> Scrolled Window -> Drawing Area`

The scrolled window fits the main window, as it is inside a vertical box. Depending on the size of the drawing area, the scrolled window shows the scroll bar. So far so good.

Now, there are several things I don't understand:

1. When the text doesn't fit the drawing area, how do I go about resizing the drawing area?
2. What is the best way of approaching the resizing when the text changes? One way I can think of is to simply handle key presses and count lines, but that doesn't seem right and probably won't work when lines wrap.
3. What events do I have to handle (and possibly propagate) for this to work?

I've tried searching the GTK docs, but they are very unhelpful in this regard. `gtk3-demo` doesn't really help, too. I know that there is https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s05.html, which describes the custom drawing a bit, but doesn't solve what I'm trying to do.

Update:
I figured out a lot by reading gedit, gtksourceview and gtk sources, which I wanted to avoid, but there seems to be no way around it.

Comment: Could you explain why you need a custom Textview?

Comment: I'm curious about the implementation and what's needed. Also, I'd like to have multiple cursors (selections) and override how they are rendered. But if there's a widget that I can somehow use and overload its methods, that might be a better stard.

Comment: I forgot to add that I also want to have my own implementation of the underlying "string".

Comment: I personally don't think it's a good idea. *a very simple text editor* will not be simple to you as you have to handle lots of things, including: linebreaking, selection, scrolling, editing itself etc. DrawingArea is just like a sheet of paper, so nobody will help you with mouse events or keyboard: you will process all clicks manually, all buttons, copy/cut/paste etc. Take a look at [GtkSourceView](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView)